# Compare two lists with different objects and create new object in one of the lists if values doesn't match

Tags: python, django, list, comparison

Let's say that I have two lists, both of them has objects.
list1 has 5 objects and list2 has 6. I want to compare them both and create new object in list1, with the checkin and checkout times, which is extra in list2.

trie comparing them as a sets. but no luck.
Thank you

```
list1 = [{'checkin': 12/10/2019, 'checkout':13/10/2019},
         {'checkin': 13/10/2019, 'checkout':14/10/2019},
         {'checkin': 14/10/2019, 'checkout':15/10/2019},
         {'checkin': 15/10/2019, 'checkout':16/10/2019},
         {'checkin': 16/10/2019, 'checkout':17/10/2019}]

list2 = [{'checkin': 12/10/2019, 'checkout':13/10/2019},
         {'checkin': 13/10/2019, 'checkout':14/10/2019},
         {'checkin': 14/10/2019, 'checkout':15/10/2019},
         {'checkin': 15/10/2019, 'checkout':16/10/2019},
         {'checkin': 16/10/2019, 'checkout':17/10/2019}
         {'checkin': 20/10/2019, 'checkout':20/10/2019}]
```

Comment: Maybe show what you have tried so far....

Comment: I don't get what you mean with comparing? Do you mean checking if item of list1 is already in list2 to avoid duplicate items in your new list?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to create a list of all the items in `list_1` and the items that are in `list_2` but not in `list_1`?

Maybe something like this (shorter lists for simplicity):

```
list_1 = [{'checkin': 12/10/2019, 'checkout':13/10/2019}]
list_2 = [{'checkin': 12/10/2019, 'checkout':13/10/2019}, {'checkin': 19/10/2019, 'checkout':20/10/2019}]


combined_list = list_1 + [x for x in list_2 if x not in list_1]
```

Don't think we can use `set()` here because of the `dicts`?